# How to default to location of the script on error in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a  Matlab(R2017b) script that is at path:

*path1: C:\ComputeCode\Scr1.m*

and a script like:

*path2:  C:\ComputeCode\OtherFiles\Scr2.m*

Scr1.m has a code which does bunch of stuff like below:

```
   %..... Scri.m.....%
   ..open files and do some processing...
   cd(path2)
   .. execute Scri2.m and do some processing ...
```

The issue is that if there is an error in  Scr2.m, the control 
does not come back to path1, but stays in path2.
How do I add some code at start of Scr1.m, so that whenever any exception/error
pccurs in matlab, it always default to path1 for execution.

Comment: use a `try`  `catch` structure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way to accomplish this would be to utilize absolute file paths rather than relative ones so you don't have to worry about having to `cd` into a directory for proper functionality.

Other methods include:

[`onCleanup`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/oncleanup.html), which executes code when the output object is destroyed. Note that this will require you to make `Scr1` a [function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/scripts-and-functions.html) in order to work with minimal additional effort.

For example, we have `SOcode.m`:

```
function SOcode
home = pwd;  % Store base directory
cleanupObj = onCleanup(@()cd(home));

cd(fullfile('./testfldr'))  % Use fullfile for platform independence
asdf
end
```

And `./asdf.m`, which contains an error:

```
disp(a)
```

Upon execution of `SOcode`, you'll receive an error:

```
>> SOcode
Undefined function or variable 'a'.

Error in asdf (line 1)
disp(a)

Error in SOcode (line 6)
asdf
```

But be returned back to the base directory.

---

Alternatively, you can use a [`try/catch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html) to catch the exception and return to the home directory before rethrowing the error. This approach does not require `Scr1` to be a function.

For example, we now have `SOcode.m`:

```
home = pwd;

cd(fullfile('./testfldr'))

try
    asdf
catch e
    cd(home)
    rethrow(e)
end
```

With the same `./asdf.m`, for the same result.

Comment: I do have Scr1.m as a function, so the method using onCleanup, worked like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

[Use `try` and `catch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html)

```
%..... Scri.m.....%  ..open files and do some processing...
try
   cd(path2)

.. execute Scri2.m and do some processing ...
catch
     cd(path1)
     break
end
```

or something similar...